# Problem with MATLAB functions

Tags: function, matlab, undefined

I got this MATLAB function. When I ran it, the following error messege showed up. Can anybody give me some hint? Thank you. The code is also shown below.

> > [h,im_matched,theta,I,J]=im_reg_MI('keyframe1.jpg','keyframe2.jpg', 0, 1)
> >     ??? Undefined function or variable "h".

Error in ==> im_reg_MI at 74
[a, b] = max(h(:));% finding the max of MI and indecises

Below is the code.

```
[h,im_matched, theta,I,J]=im_reg_MI(image1, image2, angle, step)  
[m,n]=size(image1);  
[p,q]=size(image2);   
[a,b]=size(angle);  
im1=round(image1);   

for k=1:b  
    J = rotate_image(angle(k),image2); %rotated cropped IMAGE2  
    image21=round(J);  
    [m1,n1]=size(image21);  
    for i=1:step:(m1-m)  
        for j=1:step:(n1-n)  
                im2=image21(i:(i+m-1),j:(j+n-1)); % selecting part of IMAGE2 matching the size of IMAHE1   
                im2=round(im2);   
                h(k,i,j)=MI2(im1,im2); % calculating MI  
            end  
        end  
    end  


[a, b] = max(h(:));% finding the max of MI and indecises
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually passing in image data for the `image1` and `image2` arguments. You're just passing character strings containing the image file names `'keyframe1.jpg'` and `'keyframe2.jpg'`.

You need to load the image data from the files first using [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), then pass the image data to `im_reg_MI`. Assuming the images are in the current working directory, you would do something like this:

```
image1 = imread('keyframe1.jpg');
image2 = imread('keyframe2.jpg');
[h,im_matched,theta,I,J] = im_reg_MI(image1,image2,0,1);
```

**EDIT:**

There seems to be an additional error within `im_reg_MI` that occurs if `image21` (the rotated version of `image2`) is the same size or smaller than `image1` for one or more of its dimensions. If `m1` were less than or equal to `m` and/or `n1` were less than or equal to `n`, then one or both of the loops for `i` or `j` would never be entered since `1:step:(m1-m)` and/or `1:step:(n1-n)` would [create an empty vector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html). Thus, the inner loop code would never be run and `h` would never be created.

**And one extra note...**

I noticed that the function `im_reg_MI` appears to treat the two images as 2-D, which means they must be [intensity images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-175) (i.e. grayscale or binary image data). If you're dealing with [indexed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-155) or [RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-12468) image data, I don't think `im_reg_MI` is going to handle them properly.

Comment: Hi gnovice. Thanks for the help. I followed your suggestion and pass the image data to im_reg_MI, but the same error came out again. Btw, for you information, the MI2(im1,im2) which is called in the above code is under the same directory. I guess it shouldn't be the problem. I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: @appi: I found an additional potential error within `im_reg_MI` that occurs for certain image sizes. I added an explanation of it to my answer.